# What was the scope and extent of Herbert Eulenburg's criticism of the Nazi regime during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

> During Nazi Germany, Eulenberg’s dramas were banned, his books were no
>   longer printed or sold. Yet, he stood firm against the threats of
>   party members, who continuously denounced the pacifist and humanist as
>   a “red-haired Jew”. If it had not been for his great fame he would
>   have ended up in a Nazi concentration camp.
>
> Eulenburg was a member of the Reich Chamber of Literature (part of the
>   Reich Chamber of Culture).
>
> During World War II, he published short articles under his pseudonyms
>   “Siebenkäs”, “Lynkeus” or “Der lächelnde Zuschauer” in “Der Mittag”, a
>   Düsseldorf daily newspaper. At the same time he wrote a multitude of
>   dramas, in which he sharply attacked and disputed the current
>   political situation. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Eulenberg))

Were these critical dramas published or performed?

What exactly was in those short articles?

(The website of Der Mittag seems to offer for purchase back issues, presumably scanned, but the coverage is virtually non-existent for the whole WW2 period: only a few issues from late 1939 and that of 22.11.1943 are available)

What I am trying to figure out is how much criticism was permitted, since obviously the authorities could easily shut it down if they really wanted. I also suppose that the true identity behind the pseudonyms was easily establishable.